# Checking if elements of array exists

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I was looking for a solution for a while but can't find a good one for my problem.
I want to check if existing array have specified elements if not then do something (add element).

I have associative array of data with many levels.

How I can check if element

```
$categories[][]
```

Exist within given array and contain specified data?

So far I have:

```
    $categories = array();

    foreach ($data as $category) {
      if (!in_array($category["Parent Category Name"], $categories)) {
        $categories[] = $category["Parent Category Name"];
      }
    }
```

This is working as intended so far.

I need to check if

```
$categories[][]
```

has values already inserted. I tried:

```
    $categories = array();

    foreach ($data as $category) {
      if (!in_array($category["Parent Category Name"], $categories)) {
        $categories[] = $category["Parent Category Name"];
      }

      if (!in_array($category["Parent Category Name"], $categories) && !in_array($category["Child Category1"], $categories) ) {
        if ($category["Parent Category Name"] && $category["Child Category1"]) {
          $categories[] = $category["Parent Category Name"];
          $categories[][] = $category["Child Category1"];
        }
      }
    }
```

I does not work, second if statement doesn't filter data as I want. Does not push anything in to the new array.

Can anyone suggest something or point me in the right direction.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following ...

```
$categories = [];
foreach ($data as $category) {

       if ( !isset( $categories[$category["Parent Category Name"]] ) ) {

         $categories[$category["Parent Category Name"]] = [$category["Child Category1"]];

       }else {

         if ( !in_array($category["Child Category1"],$categories[$category["Parent Category Name"]]) ) {

              array_push($categories[$category["Parent Category Name"]],$category["Child Category1"]);

         }
     }

}
```

That should work.

Comment: Thanks Victor I try that out and let you know how I am getting on with it. Thanks a lot :)